# do.call with filter function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to be able to dynamically pass search parameters to dplyr's filter function.  I can manually do a search like this:

```
filter(df, sex=='F', country=='USA')
```

but I need to be able to do this dynamically.

I tried `do.call`, like so:

```
do.call('filter',list(df,country=='USA'))
```

but that gives me an error:

> object country not found

If I put country in quotes, I don't get an error but I don't get any results back from filter.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of the situation you need this for?  You will likely need to switch to using `filter_` for standard evaluation, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26509961/2461552) and this [vignette](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/nse.Rmd) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Per aosmith suggestion I came up with:

```
 df <- data.frame(
          sex = sample(c('M','F'),10, replace = TRUE),
          country = sample(c('USA','UK'),10, replace = TRUE)
                 )

 filter_criteria <- ~ country == 'USA'
 do.call(filter_,list(df,filter_criteria))
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I didn't see an obvious elaboration that uses this approach in the situation where there are multiple criteria constructed as expressions with the `~`-function. I tried making a list of such criteria and it erred out from `lazy.eval`'s unwillingness to deal with lists or pairlists.

Comment: To use multiple criteria using `~` with `do.call` would look something like: `do.call(filter_,list(df, .dots = list(filter_criterion1, filter_criterion2)))`

Answer (score 1):

I saw the request as wanting to be able to have multiple criteria. I needed to use character representations of individual criterion and `paste` with "&" to get this to succeed. Tried several different approaches to using formula objects with consistent failure:

```
filter_criterion1 <- "country == 'USA'"
filter_criterion2 <- "sex == 'F'"
do.call(filter_, list(df,paste(filter_criterion2, filter_criterion1, sep="&")))
  sex country
1   F     USA
2   F     USA
3   F     USA
```

Thanks to aosmith for point out that the `.dots` parameter will accept lists of either character or formula specifications:

```
  do.call(filter_, list(df,.dots=list(filter_criterion2, filter_criterion1)))
  sex country
1   F     USA
2   F     USA
3   F     USA
```

Comment: I think I don't have a clear understanding the use of `do.call` in the OP - I get the same results with `filter_(df, .dots = list(filter_criterion1, filter_criterion2))` as with `do.call`, and it can take conditions in quotes or with formula as in @mr.joshuagordon answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked out away to use `filter_` in a dynamic situation with Shiny (see that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149283/2461552)) using package *lazyeval*.  Depending on what you are doing, it could be relevant, although your actual situation may be simpler.

You could do something similar by creating a vector of variables you want to condition with and vector of the same length with the conditions for each variable.

```
library(lazyeval)

variables = c("country", "sex")
conditions = c("USA", "F")
```

Then you could loop through the variables/conditions, using `interp` to create a list of the conditions you want to filter on.

```
dots = lapply(1:length(variables),
             function(crit) interp(~y == z, 
                                .values = list(y = as.name(variables[crit]), 
                                            z = conditions[crit])))
dots
[[1]]
~country == "USA"
<environment: 0x02eed660>

[[2]]
~sex == "F"
<environment: 0x02c6b388>
```

Then just use the resulting list in the `.dots` argument of `filter`.  I'm using @joshuagordon's `df` here.

```
filter_(df, .dots = dots)
  sex country
1   F     USA
2   F     USA
3   F     USA
4   F     USA
```